# Changing div to lines with java script

Tags: javascript

The "output" div should be replaced with 10 lines of output. Each
line should display two numbers separated by a space. The first number should be the line number starting
with 1. So the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4... and so on. The second number should be the factorial of the line number.
(n factorial is 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n.) That is, the numbers 1,

What should i use to create the list and to do the calculations. Tried using an array but was having difficulties in making the calculations. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show your existing markup, input and output.

Comment: Show us what you have tried for the moment + the expected output

Comment: here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/L3qh5m75/

Answer (score 2):

Check this one and try it

```
var result = '';
var lineno = 10;
for(j=1;j<=lineno;j++){
    result = result + j + '  '  + fact(j) + '<br>';
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;


function fact(n){
    var i, no, fact;
    f=1;
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++)  
  {
  f= f*i;
  }  
    return  f;
}
```

Link : https://jsfiddle.net/yrz46q85/

Comment: question asked for 10 lines, you only output 4 :p now 9 ... :p (I'm messing with you :D )

Answer (score 0):

Counting factorial to 10 in 10 lines.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var factorial = 1;
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
 factorial = factorial * i;
 output.innerHTML += i +". " + factorial + "</br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```